# SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync() is throwing System.Text.Json object cycle exception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Few days ago I decided to rewrite old API project from .net core 2.0 to 3.1 but today I faced with an error which I cannot solve. 
After rewriting "AccountManager" class _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() starts to throw error connected with Json object cycle.

Exception:

> ((System.Text.Json.JsonException)ex).Message:
>   A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

Example of usage:

```
public class AccountManager : IAccountManager{

        public ApplicationUser ActualUser { get; private set; }
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountManager(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task<LoginResponseDTO> LoginAsync(LoginRequestDTO input)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(input.Email, input.Password, false, true);
            ...
        }
}
```

Startup:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(u =>
            {
                ...
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RBDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddSignInManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<RBDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddScoped<IAccountManager,AccountManager>();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried to user and other classses attribute [JsonIgnore], but it didn't worked.
Application user class:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
        ...

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders{ get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Participation> Participations{ get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<UserProduct> UserProducts{ get; set; }
    }
```

UserManager comes from Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=3.1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

In ASP.NET Core 3.0+, it uses `System.Text.Json` by [default for JSON serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.1#new-json-serialization), and some features of `Newtonsoft.Json` may not work well with System.Text.Json (for example, Newtonsoft.Json doesn't have a maximum depth limit by default), which might cause this issue.

You can try to install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) NuGet package to add support for Newtonsoft.Json based formatters and features with following code snippet, and check if it works for you.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Besides, you can find differences between Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson