# why am I getting 'if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I made two methods for testing. `GetAllUsers` working but `GetAllRoles` throws an error like below. I don't get why this is happening? and how do I fix this?

**Update**

I solved the problem by adding a nuget package NewJson, but I am getting the new error below.

**Error**

> A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

**new error**

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

**SQLConnection with DB**

```
public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CDSPORTALContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(
                   context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CDSPORTALContextConnection"));
        }, ServiceLifetime.Transient );

    });
}
```

**AcountController**

```
[HttpGet("getAllUsers")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUsers()
{

    var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    return Ok(users);
}
[HttpGet("/getAllRoles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllRoles()
{
    var roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
    //var roles = await _appDbContext.Roles.ToListAsync(); 
    return Ok(roles);
}
```

Comment: `This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32`, For this issue, you can check this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477141/signinmanagertuser-passwordsigninasync-is-throwing-system-text-json-object-c/60502356#60502356

Comment: `A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.` Which code snippet cause this issue.